# F/flutter (10109): [FATAL:flutter/shell/common/switches.cc(133)] Check failed: mapping && size. Unable to resolve symbols: _binary_icudtl_dat

Tags: dart, flutter

After update to flutter 1.2, on build started I receive this message:

```
F/flutter (10109): [FATAL:flutter/shell/common/switches.cc(133)] Check failed: mapping && size. Unable to resolve symbols: _binary_icudtl_dat
```

Why there was no problem with flutter version 1.0 and how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you building a flutter project for fuchsia?

Comment: @shadowsheep No, for android.

Comment: It seems you are building also [flutter engine](https://github.com/flutter/engine) on your own, didn't do that before (I used prebuild sdk) so never encounter this king of issue. If this your case I suggest you to explain better your environment setup. If not I suggest you to start fresh with flutter prebuild sdk.

Comment: @VladislavLanskikh Did you find a solution for this. I am facing this issue when i shifted from Windows to Mac, but the code is same

Comment: @Nudge I returned to 1.0 version of Flutter

Comment: @VladislavLanskikh still facing same issue

Comment: @Nudge Try other versions of flutter

Comment: @VladislavLanskikh I am facing the issue on Redmi. But when I ran on different android device I worked properly. No need to change flutter version

Comment: @Nudge, thanks. But perfectly our app should work on all android devices.

Comment: @VladislavLanskikh I guess it is only a debug mode issue when ran on Redmi. When app downloaded through play store, it should work fine I guess, I am not sure.

Comment: I am having same issue on redmi, release version, distributed through internal test on play store, working fine on other phones, this flutter sdk i had upgraded from 1.0 to 1.2 on linux (ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

it was happening because of some flutter bug on redmi phones (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28208). luckily they fixed it and pushed to master few days back.  switching to master and upgrading flutter fixed this for me.
run the below commands

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

then in your project

```
flutter clean
flutter build apk
```

now release the apk to phone